# I have some questions regarding external folder use within Java

Tags: java, ftp

I have some questions regarding external folder use within Java,

I would like it so that when you load the .jar file, it creates external folders, with the names "resources", and I was wondering how I would go about doing that?

Another question is that I would like to know how to download files from my FTP server (ftp.connorwright.uk) into the "resources" folder, which will lead me onto my next question

My last question is how can I reference these external folders within my code, without any IOException errors or anything

I have tried using the CommonsIO library, but that didn't seem to help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question is easy

```
File folder = new File("path\to\your\folder\resources");
folder.mkdir();
```

You can replace "mkdir" with "mkdirs" to create the entire path of folders in case it doesn't exist

Your second question is a bit complicated, but this website has a great tutorial on it

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example

And lastly, the only way you can avoid IOExceptions is if the files you are looking for actually exists, there's no universal trick.

Hope this helps

Comment: How can I get the userhome? I think it's
String HOME = System.getPropery("user.home");

File folder = new Folder(HOME + ".stargame/res");

Comment: Is your ".stargame/res" already available in HOME directory ? If not as suggested by @DHerls you will require to check if that directory is exists or not. If its not exist first create it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, all I get now is a Security Exception